# Stopwatch time issue on repeated start/reset buttons click

Tags: javascript

When I click *start*, the count begins, and the start button hides and shows the pause and reset buttons. If I click start and reset repeatedly, the count will no longer count correctly and the reset buttons and pause buttons won't even matter anymore.

```js
var c = 0;
var t;

function count() {
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = c;
  c = c + 1;
  t = setTimeout(count, 1000);
}

function start() {
  count();
  document.getElementById("startb").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("pauseb").style.display = "inline";
}

function pause() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  document.getElementById("startb").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("pauseb").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("startb").innerHTML = "Resume";
  document.getElementById("resetb").style.display = "inline";
}

function reset() {
  c = 0;
  clearTimeout(t);
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = c;
  document.getElementById("startb").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("startb").innerHTML = "Start";
  document.getElementById("pauseb").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("resetb").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: black;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#count {
  font-size: 175px;
}

#startb {
  background-color: #800080;
  border-color: #220022;
  color: #2e002e;
}

#pauseb {
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: #b6b6b6;
}

#resetb {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: #3b0000;
  border-color: #3b0000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#lapb {
  display: none;
  background-color: #008800;
  color: black;
  border-color: darkgreen;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1>Stopwatch</h1>
<span id="count">0</span><br />
<button id="startb" onClick="start()">Start</button>
<button id="pauseb" onClick="pause()">Pause</button>
<button id="resetb" onClick="reset()">Reset</button>
<button id="lapb" onClick="lap()">Lap</button>
```

i havent tried anything im guessing multiple instances of the start function are being processed, im thinking if else statements somewhere could prevent this.

Comment: Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes your HTML. Also, be explicit about the steps to reproduce the issue, and what "buttons wont even matter anymore" means.

Comment: You are probably hitting Start multiple times before the timeout has elapsed and initiating many timeouts that overlap. Add a cleaerTimeout call to your count() function before you call setTimeout()

Comment: you need to cancel the timeout or not start another timeout if it is running

Comment: forgive me im new to stack, so this question is resolved. can i close the thread? i solved the issue by cancelling the timeout on the reset function.

Comment: Yes you can @TopD0774r

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use `setInterval` (specially not set to such an expensive *ms* interval) when in need to do frequent updates to your UI. You don't want to cog the main thread with setInterval, instead use the absolute winner in performance, and that's the [Window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).
- In HTML, don't use IDs. Why not have several watches on a single page? If you use ID-s you code becomes tightly coupled to one element only. Use classes instead
- Avoid the use of  `Element.style` from JS, instead use the Element.classList methods like `.add()`, `.remove()`

Here's a better and **performant** example for a stopwatch that previews `h+:m:s.mil`

```js
const pad = (int, pad) => String(int).padStart(pad, "0");

const stopwatch = (el) => {

  const elCount = el.querySelector(".stopwatch-count");
  const elStart = el.querySelector(".stopwatch-start");
  const elResume = el.querySelector(".stopwatch-resume");
  const elPause = el.querySelector(".stopwatch-pause");
  const elReset = el.querySelector(".stopwatch-reset");

  let timeStart;
  let timeElapsed;
  let raf;

  const draw = () => {
    const mil = timeElapsed % 1000;
    const sec = Math.floor(timeElapsed / 1000 % 60);
    const min = Math.floor(timeElapsed / 1000 / 60 % 60);
    const hou = Math.floor(timeElapsed / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    elCount.textContent = `${pad(hou)}:${pad(min, 2)}:${pad(sec, 2)}.${pad(mil, 3)}`;
  };

  const count = () => {
    timeElapsed = Date.now() - timeStart;
    draw();
    raf = requestAnimationFrame(count);
  };

  const start = () => {
    timeStart = Date.now() - timeElapsed;
    el.classList.remove("isPaused");
    el.classList.add("isStarted");
    count();
  };

  const pause = () => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
    el.classList.add("isPaused");
  };

  const reset = () => {
    cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
    
    timeStart = 0;
    timeElapsed = 0;
    timeDiff = 0;
    
    el.classList.remove("isPaused");
    el.classList.remove("isStarted");
    
    draw();
  };

  // Events:
  elStart.addEventListener("click", start);
  elPause.addEventListener("click", pause);
  elResume.addEventListener("click", start);
  elReset.addEventListener("click", reset);

  // Init:
  reset();
};

// Initialize:
document.querySelectorAll(".stopwatch").forEach(stopwatch);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 5rem;
  padding: 0.6em;
}

.stopwatch-count {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.stopwatch-start {
  background-color: green;
}

.stopwatch-resume {
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
}

.stopwatch-pause {
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
}

.stopwatch-reset {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.isStarted .stopwatch-start {
  display: none;
}

.isStarted .stopwatch-pause {
  display: initial;
}

.isPaused .stopwatch-pause {
  display: none;
}

.isPaused .stopwatch-reset {
  display: initial;
}

.isPaused .stopwatch-resume {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="stopwatch">
  <span class="stopwatch-count"></span><br />
  <button class="stopwatch-start">Start</button>
  <button class="stopwatch-resume">Resume</button>
  <button class="stopwatch-pause">Pause</button>
  <button class="stopwatch-reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

and will work for any number of stopwatch on a single page.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It has precision upto milliseconds

```js
var startTime;
var elapsedTime = 0;
var timerInterval;

function start() {
  startTime = Date.now() - elapsedTime;
  if (!timerInterval) {
    timerInterval = setInterval(updateTime, 10);
  }
}

function pause() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
  timerInterval = null;
}

function reset() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
  timerInterval = null;
  elapsedTime = 0;
  var formattedTime = formatTime(elapsedTime);
  document.querySelector(".time").textContent = formattedTime;
}

function updateTime() {
  var currentTime = Date.now();
  elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;
  var formattedTime = formatTime(elapsedTime);
  document.querySelector(".time").textContent = formattedTime;
}

function formatTime(time) {
  var hours = Math.floor(time / 3600000);
  var minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600000) / 60000);
  var seconds = Math.floor((time % 60000) / 1000);
  var milliseconds = Math.floor((time % 1000) / 10);

  return (
    pad(hours, 2) +
    ":" +
    pad(minutes, 2) +
    ":" +
    pad(seconds, 2) +
    "." +
    pad(milliseconds, 2)
  );
}

function pad(value, count) {
  var padding = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    padding += "0";
  }
  return (padding + value).slice(-count);
}
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.time {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Stopwatch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="time">00:00:00</div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button onclick="start()">Start/Resume</button>
      <button onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
      <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit:

Request animation frame is not the right solution for this use case for the following reasons:

1. There is no animation going on in here.
2. Even if there was animation going on `requestAnimationFrame` calls are paused when running in background tabs or hidden iframe tags which is not ideal for a stopwatch app

Read more about `requestAnimationFrame` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)